# React redirects to the login page after entering username and password instead of redirecting to the required page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm creating a simple react application with 3 user roles. On the login page `localhost:3000/login` I have fields for `username` and `password`. Once those details are entered and the login button is clicked, the data is sent to the backend (running node js) and that data is used to query a MySql database. If the entered data matches a user in the database, the `userId`, `name`, `password`, and `role` is sent to the backend. This data is then sent to the front end. I can read the retrieved data from the front end and up to this point it works fine. However, when I'm trying to redirect a user according to the role, say the role is doctor and I want to redirect the user to `localhost:3000/doctor` , it goes to `localhost:3000/doctor` momentarily and switches to `localhost:3000/login?`.  Shown below is the code for the login component.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import './login.css';

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  let navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleLogin = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", 
      {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response 1', response.data[0]['role'])
        if (response.data[0]['role'] === 'doctor') {
          navigate('/doctor');
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <h3>Electronic Prescription System</h3>
        <h3>Login</h3>

        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input
          className="inputs"
          type="text"
          placeholder="email"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setEmail(e.target.value)
          }}
        />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          className="inputs"
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={handleLogin}>Log in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Login;
```

If I remove all the code inside the `handleLogin` function and just have `navigate('/doctor');` it redirects properly.

The routes are inside the Main component as shown below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from "./pages/Login/Login";
import Doctor from "./pages/Doctor/Doctor";
import Patient from "./pages/Patient/Patient";
import Pharmacy from "./pages/Pharmacy/Pharmacy";

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="doctor" element={<Doctor />} />
      <Route path="patient" element={<Patient />} />
      <Route path="pharmacy" element={<Pharmacy />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

The `Doctor` Component:

```
import { HeaderPanel } from '../../components/headerPanel/headerPanel'
import { PrescribePanel } from '../../components/prescribePanel/prescribePanel'
import { PrescriptionsList } from '../../components/prescriptionsList/prescriptionsList'
import './styles.css';

export const Doctor = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HeaderPanel />
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <PrescribePanel />
        <PrescriptionsList />
      </div>
    </> 
  );
}

export default Doctor
```

I'm using `react-router-dom` version 6.6.1 and the `react` version is 18.2.0.

Tried using a `useEffect` hook to capture the role changing and redirecting, but id did not work either.

Comment: What's the code inside the Doctor component?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis the code is 
```
export const Doctor = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <HeaderPanel />
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <PrescribePanel />
                <PrescriptionsList />
            </div>
        </> 
    );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible your login component is also redirecting in another point, and it happens after `handleLogin` makes its own redirect? It would help to add the complete code for `Login` and `Doctor` components.

Comment: show the code where you call ```handleLogin```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any code that is navigating to the `"/login"` route. You should include enough code to be considered a [mcve].

Comment: @CésarRodriguez I have edited the question and added the code for both Login and Doctor components

Comment: @AbdulMahamaliyev  I have edited the question and added the code for Login  component which calls the handleLogin function

Comment: @DrewReese the only place that includes code to navigate to the ```/login``` route is from the Main component as shown above. I usually enter ```localhost:3000/login```  to go to the login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suspect is happening here is that the "log in" `button` is submitting the form which takes the default form action and reloads the page, the current route path being `"/login"`. `button` elements have a `type="submit"` attribute value by default.

To resolve I'd suggest attaching `handleLogin` to the `form` element's `onSubmit` event handler and calling `preventDefault` on the `onSubmit` event object to prevent submitting the form and prevent reloading the page. This should allow the authentication logic to complete as expected.

Try to get yourself in the habit of being specific with the `button` element's `type` attribute.

```
const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = (e) => { // <-- onSubmit event object
    e.preventDefault();        // <-- don't take form action

    Axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3001/login", 
      { email, password },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data[0]['role'] === 'doctor') {
          navigate('/doctor');
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}> // <-- form onSubmit event handler
        <h3>Electronic Prescription System</h3>
        <h3>Login</h3>

        <label>
          Email Address
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="text"
            placeholder="email"
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Password
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="password"
            placeholder="password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>

        <button type="submit"> // <-- be specific with button type
          Log in
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```